# Selenium random click to Div's

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I am testing a website and I want to get one of div's randomly and click to it.

Every Div has picture of product.

The website is this :

https://www.trendyol.com/tum--urunler?q=bilgisayar&qt=bilgisayar&st=bilgisayar

[image]

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code:

```
List<WebElement> div_elements = driver.findElememts(By.xpath(“//div[@class=‘p-card-wrppr’]”));
Random random = new Random();
int num = random.nextInt(div_elements.size());
div_elements.get(num).click();
```

I have assumed you want to click any of the div with class p-card-wrppr. If you want divs with different class change your xpath accordingly.

Comment: @Batuhan Bakar sorry it should be nextInt . I missed it. Try now I have updated the code.

Comment: @BatuhanBakar You should accept / up vote answer if it solves your issue. Reason : It helps others with similar issue as accepted answers have more visibility. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed in java, but what you would do is get the total number of divs, and then generate a random number between 1 and N, and click it.  In c# it would look something like this:

```
// This will get you the number of DIVs under the 'prdct-cntnr-wrppr' class
int numDivs = driver.WebDriver.GetXpathCount("//*[@class='prdct-cntnr-wrppr']/div");
Random ran = new Random();
int randomNum = ran.Next(1,numDivs); // generates a random number between 1 and number of divs
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//*[@class='prdct-cntnr-wrppr']/div[{0}]", randomNum))).Click();
```

Note that this will only work if you're looking at the same level of divs.  If you want sub-divs, then that's a little different, but more or less the same.

Comment: You could also get all divs from the document, add them to a list and then select one from the list randomly, has more overhead, but less chance of one div falling through the cracks due to nesting changes in the document.